# Convert control sequences to right characters

Tags: c, string, char

I am going to write a program in C which rewrites string t to s variables and converts characters such as new line, tabulation to control sequences such as \n, \t. Next, I need to write a function that does reverse operation - converts control sequences to right characters.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIMIT 50

void escape(char * s, const char * t);
void bumpInto(char * s, const char * t);

int main(void) {
    const char s1[LIMIT] = "Ala\nma\tkota.";
    char s2[LIMIT];
    char s3[LIMIT];
    printf("%s\n", s1);
    escape(s2, s1);
    printf("%s\n", s2);
    bumpInto(s3, s2);
    printf("%s\n", s3);
    return 0;
}

void escape(char * s, const char * t) {
    while (*t) {
        switch (*t) {
        case '\n':
            *s = '\\';
            ++s;
            *s = 'n';
            break;
        case '\t':
            *s = '\\';
            ++s;
            *s = 't';
            break;
        default:
            *s = *t;
            break;
        }
        ++s;
        ++t;
    }
}

void bumpInto(char * s, const char * t) {
    char prev = 0;
    while (*t) {
        if (prev == '\\') {
            switch (*t) {
            case 'n':
                --s;
                *s = '\n';
                break;
            case 't':
                --s;
                *s = '\t';
                break;
            }
        }
//        if (prev != '\\' && *t != '\\')
            *s = *t;
        putchar(*s);
        prev = *t;
        ++s;
        ++t;
    }
}
```

I have results:

```
Alanmatkota.@
```

instead of expected:

```
Ala
ma       kota.
```

I have problem with writing bumpInto function that does reverse operation than escape, specifically convert control sequences to right characters. Can anyone make suggestions how to do it?

Comment: You need to do only one thing: either `=='\\'` branch or the opposite. What you do now overwrites the results of the switch. Also, there is a more elegant way to do it than keeping `prev`.

Comment: @Arkadiy what should I specifically do?

Comment: When you see a `\`, you should do one thing. When you see another character, you should do another thing. Sapienti sat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rewriting your control characters:

```
 *s = *t;
```

gets executed every time. Just add an else:

```
void bumpInto(char * s, const char * t) {
    char prev = 0;
    while (*t) {
        if (prev == '\\') {
            switch (*t) {
            case 'n':
                --s;
                *s = '\n';
                break;
            case 't':
                --s;
                *s = '\t';
                break;
            }
        }else
            *s = *t;
        putchar(*s);
        prev = *t;
        ++s;
        ++t;
    }
 *s = *t; // add null terminator '/0'
}
```

BTW, you were not coping the null terminator of the string.